# Execute loop on bash thru keywords

Tags: bash

I have such script, it search my mail files and if keyword is found it move all files to other location.

How to make it work for multiple keywords?, for example i would have 11 KEY's and i would not want to copy and paste find command over and over.

```
DIRF='move/from'
DIRT='move/to'
KEY='discount'

find $DIRF -type f -exec grep -ilR "$KEY" {} \; | xargs -I % mv % $DIRT
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `find` here at all?

You are already telling `grep` to operate recursively (`-R`) so just point it at `$DIRF` and be done. `-R` is also pointless if you only ever give it files (from `type -f`).

Also `grep` takes a pattern that can do alternation. Just use that.

```
grep -RilE 'KEY1|KEY2|KEY3|Key4' "$DIRF"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for KEY in "discount"  "other_value" "other_value2"
do
    find $DIRF -type f -exec grep -ilR "$KEY " {} \; | xargs -I % mv % $DIRT
done
```

Comment: This olso works alright i wonder if i want to add two arrays for directories so i would want to have many DIRF DIRT and loop whoole process thru pairs of thoose dirs, howto do that ?